# SASI Index in Cassandra

Tags: indexing, cassandra

Is SASI INDEX available for Cassandra 2.1+ ?

[Link 1](https://github.com/xedin/sasi) - [Link 2](http://slides.com/hannelitavante-hannelita/sasi-and-secondary-indexes#/0/45) - [Link 3](http://rustyrazorblade.com/2016/02/cassandra-secondary-index-preview-1/)

I found it useful for looking up in my tables in Cassandra, where I had problems in where Clause before. But it seems that it's unavailable for newer versions.

Comment: SASI index will be available from 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SASI was originally developed for 2.1 and was available as a patch. The version included in the mainline of Cassandra starts at 3.4. There were a lot if significant changes in the syntax and implementation since the 2.1 version, so I suggest starting there.